# To change the value of an empty variable

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a loop like this:

```
[centers, radii]=imfindcircles() %find circles in the image
if isnan(centers)==1 %if centres is empty
    centers='NA'; % assign centres a NA
else
    centers=centers;
end
```

What I want to do is:

- when no circles found and `centers=[]`, I want to assign centres a value (could be `'NA'` or `0`).
- if some circles found, then `centres` remains the same array.

The goal of this loop is to assign `centres` some value so that I can save it into a .xls file even if there is no circles found.

But my problem is after this loop, even if `centers=[]`, `centres` will not change its value. This means this loop doesn't work at all. So could somebody check for me where is wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles() %find circles in the image

if (isempty(centers)) %if centres is empty
    centers(1) = NaN; % assign centres a NA
end
```

A better theoretical approach would be, IMHO:

```
if (isempty(centers))
    % write a dummy XLS file
else
    % write your values to XLS file
end
```

Comment: You edited your answer and made it exactly the same as the other answer. From the reputation change, it is also evident that you downvoted the other answer just because someone downvoted yours.

Comment: Yeah because a method to accomplish a one liner operation it totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
function [ x ] = empty2nan( x, Size )
   if isempty(x), x=nan(1,Size); end
end
```

And

```
centers=empty2nan(centers,2)
```